# How to send video to email in android programatically

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to send the 30 sec video to email from my android application.i have sent the email with image attachment but it is not working for video.plese help me to do that Thanks in advance.

```
send.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(
    android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.setType("video/3gp");
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
    new String[] { address.getText().toString() });
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
    subject.getText());
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
    emailtext.getText());
    String dataPath = "/sdcard/video0007.3GP"; 
   emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(dataPath));
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent,"Send mail..."));
  }
});
```

Comment: @sandip armal i just use this code to send the text and image as an attachment to email can we send video also like this?

Comment: (Action_send) are external intent which can also send video.u need to browse the video from sd card and then send it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this code for pick an video from SD card then send email with video.....

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sendIntent.setType("video/3gp");
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Video");
       sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://sdcard/dcim/Camera/filename.3gp"));
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Enjoy the Video");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Email:"));
```

use this code for send email then browse your video...if any error or problem occur...let me know...

**Edited Answer**

```
private void message() 
    {

        Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
        String shareBody = "Here is the share content body";
        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject Here");
        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Send via"));

    }
```

Comment: Thnaks for reply where i need to make changes i cant able to understan please help me

Comment: u need simple answer.....use Action_send for sending email and then browse attachment(video) from sd card...

Comment: I used the above code only text message is sending attached video is not sent to mail

Comment: means you want to sent text message with video or mms with video?

Comment: How it possible to send video with text message..... when you attach any file to your text message then this message will become a MMS. If you want to send video with MMS then it's possible....

Comment: yeah i want to send video with MMS Please tell me how to do that

Comment: check my edited answer....whenever it open message screen, attach option will open by pressing menu button...

Comment: but it is showing dialogue with facebook message,Peep etc.i want to diaplay only Mail option is it possible

Comment: then uninstall peep and Facebook from your emulator for temporary. action_send intent are use to send data using mobile application which are already install....just uninstall it for some time.