# how can i attach video in email , email is sending in backgroud not user interface in android

Tags: android, email, video, background

A video Record in background and that is also save in internal memory .
but how can I attach it to email and send mail in background .

Thanks.

Comment: Lots of similar question available. check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942109/how-to-send-video-to-email-in-android-programatically).

Comment: @Neha Agarwal : i have tried , but this is all in Intent ..... not in Background ... so how can i attach my video to email body ..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10121660/how-to-record-video-from-background-of-application-android      see i use this link for sending email ,, in this email i want to attach my video file .

Comment: How you are sending message in background?